# Can Mail.app be configured to insert a blank line before the text of the previous message in a reply?

Tags: mail.app

Currently, a reply window contains this:

> *new message text starts here*
> ... old/previous message text starts here...

What I want is this

> *new message text starts here*
>
> ... old/previous message text starts here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not ideal but:

Go into Preferences: Signatures, create a new Signature, erase the name and e-mail address, and hit Enter once to create a blank line. Then check the "Place signature above quoted text" box.

Note: once a signature has been saved with actual text, Mail won't let you blank it out, so make sure you do this with a new sig, rather than editing an old one.

Comment: That did it. Was a bit tricky and I had to fiddle around a bit in the signature settings, but I got it to work. Behaves just as I wanted now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can configure the free [QuoteFix](http://code.google.com/p/quotefixformac/) Mail plugin to do what you want.

Comment: Good idea! When I can solve a problem without needing additional software I'll always choose that option, though.

Thanks anyway!